# Is there an easier way to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (4 x)}{\left(x^4+5 x ^ 2+4\right)^2} d x $

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

This question may be a little silly, but in a recent test I was asked to evaluate this integral, which I now know how to calculate with a contour integral, but doing the residues for two double poles seems absolutely insane in such short time, as the derivatives look horrible, so I was wondering if I am missing some faster method.

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (4 x)}{\left(x^4+5 x ^ 2+4\right)^2}\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: This problem was on an exam of yours? Are you sure the professor wasn't testing to see who brought a calculator into the exam? lol. This took me 20 minutes

Comment: Mostly because I was rederiving the partial fraction for (xy)^2 as /x, /x^2, /y, /y^2 and I thought there might have been a /xy term but of course not.. But yeah slightly tricky.

Answer (score 2):

You can do partial fraction first and compute residues term by term

$$\frac{1}{(x^4+5x^2+4)^2}=\frac{2}{27}\cdot\frac{1}{x^2+4}+\frac{1}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{(x^2+4)^2}-\frac{2}{27}\cdot\frac{1}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$x^4+5x^2+4=(x+i)(x-i)(x+2i)(x-2i)$$ using partial fracion decomposition leads to

$$\frac{1}{\left(x^4+5 x^2+4\right)^2}=-\frac{i}{108 (x+i)}-\frac{19 i}{864 (x-2 i)}+\frac{19 i}{864 (x+2 i)}-\frac{1}{36
   (x+i)^2}-$$ $$\frac{1}{144 (x-2 i)^2}-\frac{1}{144 (x+2 i)^2}+\frac{i}{108
   (x-i)}-\frac{1}{36 (x-i)^2}$$

So, you face two types of integrals
$$I_{1,k}=\int \frac {\cos(4x)}{(x+k i)}\,dx\qquad \text{and }\qquad I_{2,k}=\int \frac {\cos(4x)}{(x+k i)^2}\,dx$$ Use the obvious change of variable $x+k i=y$ to make for example
$$\frac {\cos(4x)}{(x+k i)}=\frac{\cos (4 (y-i k))}{y}=\frac{\cosh (4 k) \cos (4y)+i \sinh (4 k) \sin (4y)}{y}$$ Now, $z=4y$ to make
$$I_{1,k}=\int \frac {\cos(4x)}{(x+k i)}\,dx=\cosh (4 k)\int  \frac {\cos(z)} z \,dz +i \sinh (4 k)\int  \frac {\sin(z)} z \,dz $$ which are well known.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is easy to get
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(4x)}{x^2+a}dx=\frac{e^{-4\sqrt a}}{\sqrt a}
\end{eqnarray}
by a contour integral. So
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(4x)}{(x^2+a)(x^2+b)}dx=\frac1{b-a}\bigg(\frac{e^{-4\sqrt b}}{\sqrt b}-\frac{e^{-4\sqrt a}}{\sqrt a}\bigg)
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(4x)}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2+4)^2}dx=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a\partial b}\frac1{b-a}\bigg(\frac{e^{-4\sqrt b}}{\sqrt b}-\frac{e^{-4\sqrt a}}{\sqrt a}\bigg)\bigg|_{a=1,b=4}&=&\frac{43+88e^4}{432e^8}\pi.
\end{eqnarray}